# Replacing bits in a Byte Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap, byte

I want to open a Bitmap File in C# as an array of bytes, and replace certain bytes within that array, and rewrite the Byte array back to disk as a bitmap again.

My current approach is to read into a byte[] array, then convert that array to a list to begin editing individual bytes.

```
originalBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
List<byte> listBytes = new List<Byte>(originalBytes);
```

How does one go about replacing every nth byte in the array with a user configured/different byte each time and rewriting back to file?

Comment: Are you aware, that you are using `byte`, which is not the same as `bit`? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Apologies for the error, it has been clarified. I'd like to replace bytes within the array, for example replace a byte with an ASCII byte character (stenography).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need in `List<byte>`

replaces every n-th byte with `customByte`

```cs
var n = 5;
byte customByte = 0xFF;

var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    if (i%n == 0)
    {
        bytes[i] = customByte;
    }
}

File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
```

Comment: Agree. Beat me to it.

Comment: What if I wanted to change the byte each time?

Comment: incrementing `i` by `n` would make it a bit faster

Comment: @ThomasD. yep, you are right. That would probably be a better practice.

Comment: @Anton8000 each time what? run the code as many times as you want. But consider to increment `i` by `n` as @ThomasD. wrote if performance matters

Comment: For each subsequent byte written, a different byte is written. For example, splitting a word down into bytes of ASCII and writing each letter to the nth value.

Comment: @Anton8000 you can change `customByte` right after the byte is written. Also you can write a method and use it in for-cycle `bytes[i] = GetNextByte()`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to replace every nth byte with the same new byte, you could do something like this (shown for every 3rd byte):

```
int n = 3;
byte newValue = 0xFF;
for (int i = n; i < listBytes.Count; i += n)
{
  listBytes[i] = newValue;
}

File.WriteAllBytes(path, listBytes.ToArray());
```

Of course, you could also do this with a fancy LINQ expression which would be harder to read i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can implement something like this:

```
 // ReadAllBytes returns byte[] array, we have no need in List<byte>
 byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

 // starting from 0 - int i = 0 - will ruin BMP header which we must spare 
 // if n is small, you may want to start from 2 * n, 3 * n etc. 
 // or from some fixed offset
 for (int i = n; i < data.Length; i += n)
   data[i] = yourValue;

 File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);
```

Please notice, that *Bitmap* file has a *header*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

that's why I've started loop from `n`, not from `0`